# Why can i use requests in Python shell but i get the error no module found in Django?

Tags: django, import, module, python-requests

I get the error module not found when trying to import requests in Django.

I cannot get python module requests to work in Django. I have installed the module using pip in python and can import in the python terminal.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

if I run the commands in python shell:

```
>>> import requests
>>> test = requests.get(url="http://192.168.9.186:2480/connect/test")
```

i get a htto 204 response but in django I just get the module error

Comment: Is your Django App executed in the same (virtual)env as your shell?

Comment: Swap to whatever virtual env you are using for the django project, and run `pip freeze`  - then post the output please.

Comment: astroid==2.2.5
colorama==0.4.1
Django==2.1.7
isort==4.3.16
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.3.1
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
typed-ast==1.3.1
wrapt==1.11.1

Comment: @H4kor no the shell is basic python 3.7 shell and I run import requests and then perform the get and it works fine. However, when i use import requests in django views.py i get an unresolved import error as it fails to recognise requests.

Comment: As your pip freeze of the django virtualenv shows, requests is no installed in that env. run pip install requests in the the django virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @H4kor my naive understanding of Python and Django I assumed they were using the same code library. After I ran:

```
pip install requests
```

The code ran through and resolved the error. Appreciate the help for this novice.